# How to check internet access is enabled in android?

Tags: android, application-settings

Iam trying to create an application that connect to a webserver and retricve data,
i want to  do some functions

1. when i click my application, first it check whether the internet access is enabled?
   if it is enabled it start the application , else open the internet access settings..after that it redirect to my application....
2. when the application is connecting to web-server, connection is  timed out after a specific time if the connection is not success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In an application of mine, I have a class defined like this:

```
    public class ConnectionDetector {

        private Context _context;

        public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
            this._context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Checking for all possible internet providers
         * **/
        public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
              if (connectivity != null)
              {
                  NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                  if (info != null)
                      for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                          if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                          {
                              return true;
                          }

              }
              return false;
        }
    }
```

And in the Activity that I need to check the connectivity status, I use this:

```
    // DEFINE THIS AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
```

In the `onCreate()`:

```
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
            "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }
```

Oh. Almost forgot. If you also need to re-direct the user to the settings panel to activate Internet, you can use an Intent like this:

You could prompt the user in the AlertDialog and let them choose if they want to. If yes, run this piece of code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:**

I missed the obvious (*Commonsware pointed that one out in his comment*).

You will need to add the **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** permission to your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: @Sibinfrancis: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: Note that this requires `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission, last I checked. It also does not "check internet access is enabled in android" -- it checks to see if there is an active network. There is nothing in this code that confirms that the network can reach any host on the Internet (e.g., firewall rules).

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for pointing that out. I never personally faced a situation where firewalls were affecting this check. Neither has any user. Any pointers on how to implement such a check?

Comment: @SiddharthLele: Actually try hitting the target server with a request. If this code did not require additional permissions, I'd say use it, then if it checks out OK do a controlled request to the server. However, since this code *does* require an additional permission, I am less than convinced that it adds enough value to be worth the permission. While `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is not terribly scary, some percentage of prospective users will not install an app requesting it, either because of that permission, the permission in combination with others, or due to the size of the permission list.

Comment: @CommonsWare: So a _ping_ of sorts and check for a response. It certainly makes a lot of sense. I will start making such a provision in my apps. And update the post with the code after testing. However, on a personal note, a couple of libraries in my app need the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` anyway, so that will have to stay. Thanks a ton for the pointer. :-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele: "So a ping of sorts and check for a response" -- yes, though perhaps not literally a `ping`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method:

```
public boolean isConn() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
            if (connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And add this permission to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I use to check internet connectivity

```
// Checks Internet Status
public boolean isOnline() {
    if(cm == null)
        return false;

    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Also add this permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

To send the user to WiFi settings page use

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: if net is not available how to redirect to internet settings option??

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Ahmed Aeon Axan