# Best way to check internet connection in whole app

Tags: java, android, class, internet-connection

I want to check internet connection in whole app. I've googled for it, but the result was everyone creates an instance method in each class and tries to check the internet connection. My plan is to create a class with static method and check it without instantiating my class. **Is it good idea to do that? Or should I try another way?** My plan is to do something like this:

```
public class CheckInternetConnecting {

    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
         ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
            cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply make your method static

Comment: Take a look at this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922229/450534

Comment: No problems doing this other than perhaps it is hard to create unit tests for since it's a static method and you cant just mock that (easilly).

Comment: Is it true to instantiating a class in static method? I want use it in my whole app, for each call would be create an instance of ConnectivityManager class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is totally fine. I would recommend to add a **package Utils** to your project and put Helper-Classes in there. So instead of a class CheckInternetConnecting, create a class **NetworkHelper** and put your static method in there.

**Adding a package:**
On the left side of eclipse, in your package explorer right click your src folder and add a new package. It's important to include your package name, e.g when your package name is com.my.project than add a package called com.my.project.utils... Then you can add your NetworkHelper class to the new package by e.g right clicking and adding a new file. Copy your static code into the NetworkHelper and then you're all set...

Comment: @Chris Conway thanks for replying I caught what you said.It works fine

Comment: Glad to hear - you can mark my answer as correct (by pressing the green check mark) if it resolved your problem... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the internet connectivity in the following way..

```
public boolean testConnection() {

    try {
        boolean connectionStatus=false;

        InetAddress addr=InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8");//google dns 8.8.8.8


        connectionStatus=addr.isReachable(1000); // 1second time for response

    }                               
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return connectionStatus;
}
```

Comment: There would be some packet losses on network. Increase the response time from 1000ms (1 Second) to 2000ms (2 Seconds).

Comment: i tried with 10 seconds too, always returns false for 8.8.8.8 for me. might be a permission problem (it seems when icmp is not allowed tcp port 7 is checked). i can get it to work if i run java with super user permissions, but this is definitely not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can consider registering a broadcast receiver and listening out for connectivity changes as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges).